# Deleting unwanted columns starting at a specific row - excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason I can't figure out how to do this... it seems so basic:

Trying to delete unwanted columns starting at a specific row.

Example:
Want to delete Columns C, D, E, M, N and L all starting at row 10 of Wsh2.

```
'deleting columns that are unwanted
Cells(wsh2.Cells("C10"), wsh2.Cells("C10").End(xlDown)).EntireColumn.Delete
Cells(wsh2.Cells("D10"), wsh2.Cells("C10").End(xlDown)).EntireColumn.Delete
Cells(wsh2.Cells("E10"), wsh2.Cells("C10").End(xlDown)).EntireColumn.Delete
Cells(wsh2.Cells("M10"), wsh2.Cells("C10").End(xlDown)).EntireColumn.Delete
Cells(wsh2.Cells("N10"), wsh2.Cells("C10").End(xlDown)).EntireColumn.Delete
Cells(wsh2.Cells("L10"), wsh2.Cells("C10").End(xlDown)).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

I've adapted a previous code that I found on here that used Range. I've also attempted using Union and Range but cant seem to figure it out.

Basically: Trying to delete only specific columns starting at a particular row after I've copied a range of rows from a previous worksheet.

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: So you are not trying to delete the entire column, but just clear the data from row 10 and below?

Comment: Clear the data from row 10 and below and then I guess hide the column that was cleared so it doesn't show gaps between the columns that were cleared and the columns that the data was kept in

Comment: Will there still be data in rows 1 - 9? If you hide the columns you'll be omitting that data as well.

Comment: No there is no data in 1 - 9. That is a good point though if there was.

Comment: Hey @MAJ10, I saw a post you made earlier, and because it got downvoted a couple times, I guess you deleted it ... couldn't think of another way to contact you, but I have a solution for your deleted question if you wanted it ... (comment with @brw59) in the text so it'll notify me

Comment: @brw59 I'd love to see your solution! that would be great.

Comment: @MAJ10 provide me with a way to get it to you, or suggest a different way, since you deleted your question I can't get it to you that way

Comment: @brw59 I'll create a new question, with the same material + some more to maybe make it easier for you to understand!

Comment: I'll look out for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use EntireColumn.Delete it will delete the entire column, you need to get the range and delete that instead, eg.

```
Range("C10:C" & Rows.Count).Delete
```

Comment: For some reason i get run time error 1004 when i try this

Comment: Try: wsh2.Range("C10:C" & wsh2.Rows.Count).Delete  if that does't work please post your updated code

Comment: @MAJ10 Run-time error 1004 is _always_ due to unqualified use of `Rows`. Follow the advice in the comment.

Comment: I've posted my entire code for the sheet if it makes more sense. I'll attempt what @jmdon said again. Thanks

Comment: wsh2.Range("C10:C").Delete should be wsh2.Range("C10:C" & wsh2.Rows.Count).Delete and so forth. Also I note you have stated there is no data in rows 1 to 9, so why not just use Columns(3).Delete?

Comment: I have it formatted from rows 1-9 with some headers, etc (a template), So i'm trying not to delete that. But, Columns(3).Delete does seem to work....might be able to play around with this and make it work. Appreciate it! @jmdon

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually want to delete the *entire* column, as you stated.  You want to clear cells `C10:Cend`, `D10:Dend`, `E10:Eend`, `M10:Mend`, `N10:Nend`, and `L10:Lend`.  This is what you want to have your code do.  Navigate to the cell of choice, and clear all cells below that specific coordinate.

For ease, you could just loop through all cells from `C10` to `C10000` and delete the contents of each cell, for example, which would be very simple to implement, though potentially not the most efficient.

Comment: Or just use `Range("C10:C" & Rows.Count).Delete`, as jmdon mentions in his answer.  Much more efficient.